Is there a way to (query) values from merged cells in Google sheets?
Sheet
A1 is merged with B1. They contain a value "John"
Is there a way when I type =B1, the value of A1 is the result?
I mean whenever two cells in a row are merged, the value of the rightmost cell is the same as the value of the leftmost one.


I mean whenever two cells in a row are merged, the value of the rightmost cell is the same as the value of the leftmost one.

No. Under the covers, only the top-left cell in a merged group of cells contains a value. The rest are empty.
You could do something like
=IF(LEN(B1),B1,A1)

or
=CHOOSECOLS(A1:B1,COUNTA(A1:B1))

